# Magento - How to check when a item has been added to cart

Tags: magento, highlight, cart

I would like to know if anyone can answer the following question.
How can you check when an item has been added to the cart?
I need to do some highlighting when a item has been added, but i can't figure out how.

Anyone know?

I'm rather new at magento, so sorry for my noobish question :)

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the cart items like this :

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItems();
foreach($items as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
               ->loadByAttribute('sku',$item->getSku());
    //... 
}
```

or another way would be to handle the product add to cart event, maybe it fits your needs better, as Mage will do this :

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after',
                    array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));
```

right after adding the product to the cart.

Comment: checkout_cart_product_add_after that event actually happens before the item is added to the cart. though in this question it will serve OPs purpose